# Norming subsets of the dual ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Suppose $S$ is a subset of $B_{X^*}$, the unit ball of $X^*$, that is *norming* in the sense that for any $x\in X$, $||x||=\sup_{f\in S}|f(x)|$. Is it true that $B_{X^*}$ is the $w^*$-closure of convex hull of $\pm S$?

Comment: For a counter example consider $X=\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: @s.harp can u explain

Comment: @mathworker21 on $\Bbb C^n$ the weak* topology is the norm topology. But for example the unit sphere (and many other sets not equal to the unit ball!) have this norming property and are closed. You can also assume $S$ be convex, take a closed half.sphere and its interior for example.

Comment: @mathworker21 Made changes, hopefully it is meaningful now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be the weak-* closure of the convex hull of $\pm S$. Then $C$ is a closed convex subset of $B_{X^*}$. 
Let $f \in B_{X^*} \backslash C$. 
By Hahn-Banach in the locally convex space $X^*$ with its weak-* topology (such that only evaluations at a point of $X$ are linear forms), there is some $x \in X$ and some $a > 0$ such that, for all $g \in S$, $|g(x)| < a < f(x)$.

In particular, $|f(x)| > a \geq \|x\|$, a contradiction.

So $C=B_{X^*}$.

Comment: What statement of Hahn Banach are you using? What is the number $a$ and what are $g,f$? Why is $a≥\|x\|$? I ask these questions because it seems to me even with the extra conditions that $S$ is convex and $S=-S$ you can construct infinite-dimensional examples where the closure of $S$ fails to be $B_{X^*}$.

Comment: @s.harp $a \ge ||x||$ since $\sup_{g \in S} |g(x)| = ||x||$ and $a > |g(x)|$ for all $g \in S$.

Comment: Let $E=X^*$ be endowed with the weak-* topology. Then $x \in X \rightarrow (u \longmapsto u(x)) \in E^*$ is an isomorphism. $C \subset B_{X^*}$ is norming, closed, convex. If $f \in B_{X^*} \backslash C$, from the hyperplane separation theorem ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem ), there are scalars $a<b$ and a $x \in X$ such that for all $g \in C$, $g(x) < a < b < f(x)$. As a consequence, $\|x\| \leq \sup_{g \in C}\,g(x) \leq a$, while $\|x\| \geq |||f|||\|x\| \geq f(x) > b$. A contradiction.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what you have written.  Would you take a look at the coutner-example I have written below?

Comment: I believe you are considering explicitly _real_ vector spaces.

Comment: @s.harp: Yes, seeing your counter-example, this seems to be the key point. In complex vector spaces, there is a real part popping up in the separation theorem which invalidates the end of the proof. Note that it is solved if, in the norming definition, you take the sup of the real parts of the $g(x)$, $g \in S$, instead of the $|g(x)|$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counter-example in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Let $H$ be an arbitrary infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and consider $H'=\Bbb C\oplus H$. Let $B_H$ be the unit ball in $H$ and denote $[-1,1]\subseteq \Bbb C$ as embedded into $H'$ by $A$ (and denote the vector $1$ in $A$ by $\mathfrak a$). Then define

$$S= \{ \sqrt t\, x + \sqrt{1-t}\, y\,\mid t\in[0,1], x\in A, y\in B_H\}$$

now note that $S=-S$, that $S$ is convex and that $S\subseteq B_{H'}$. We may further charcterise (or alternatively define) $S$ as the norm $≤1$ elements of $H'$ such that the $A$ component is real.

Let $v\in H'$ and split $v=re^{i\varphi}\,\mathfrak{a}+y$ for $y\in H$. Note that $\|v\|^2 = r^2+\|y\|^2$, we define
$$v':=\frac{r\,\mathfrak{a}+e^{-i\varphi}y}{\|v\|},$$ 
which is in $S$. We check that (here the second component of the scalar product is the anti-linear one)
$$\langle v, v'\rangle = \frac1{\|v\|}\langle re^{i\varphi}\,\mathfrak{a} + y, r\,\mathfrak{a}+e^{-i\varphi} y\rangle  = \frac1{\|v\|}(r^2e^{i\varphi}\,\mathfrak{a}+e^{i\varphi}\|y\|^2)=e^{i\varphi}\|v\|,$$
hence $|\langle v,v'\rangle|=\|v\|$ and $S$ has the norming property.

Now check that $S$ is weak* closed. This is more or less obvious, as if $x_\alpha\in S$ then the $A$ component of $x_n$ is equal to $\langle x_\alpha,\mathfrak a\rangle$, which must be real. If $x_\alpha$ converges weakly to $x$ then $\langle x_\alpha,\mathfrak a\rangle\to \langle x,\mathfrak a\rangle$ must also be real. Since $B_{H'}$ is weak* closed anyway it follows that any limit of an element in $S$ must be in $B_{H'}$ with real $A$ component, hence the limit must lie in $S$.